# Why does the whiskermenu shortcut on "Super L" opens AND closes my whiskermenu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, whisker

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) with xfce4.
Since I have upgraded to this version, my Super L shortcut for the whiskermenu appears to be broken. Pushing the Super L key correctly opens the whiskermenu, but releasing the key will also close it again. This is obviously not intended behaviour.

I have tried to change the shortcut to other keys and Super R for example works like a charm. I can also press the Super L key quite long (a second or so), then, releasing it will not again close the whiskermenu.
What is so special about Super L?
Do I have to remove all shortcuts containing a Super L + *?
How can I fix this?

Thank you! <3

Comment: 22.04 added a little program to autorun, which binds Super L to Ctrl-Escape, to allow using it as a shortcut for the Whisker menu without breaking other shortcuts containing Super. You could disable it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes! This was exactly the problem! Thank you so much! =] If you convert it to an answer, I will make it the accepted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart -> Bind Super Key = off.

Xubuntu 22.04 adds a sneaky program to autorun (`xcape`), which binds Super L to Ctrl-Escape, supposedly allowing it to open Whisker menu without breaking other shortcuts involving Super.

It probably interferes with the way you set this shortcut yourself.

Comment: Would be good if you could be more specific about this "sneaky program". Is it `xcape`?

Comment: @vanadium In the settings it's named `Bind Super Key`. Seems to call `xcape`, yes.

Comment: Would be good to add this to the answer (and correct the typo on the last line in the mean time).

Comment: @vanadium Done.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted already before ;)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me after upgrading to 22.04 and nearly going crazy in the 5 minutes where I kept using my keyboard shortcut and the menu kept disappearing immediately.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I was wondering why I couldn't bind Super+Right to Tile Window Right. Everything said "it's because Super opens Whisker Menu", but in the keyboard settings Whisker Menu was opened by Ctrl+Esc. Little did I know that `xcape -e Super_L Control_L Escape` was running in the background (how sneaky). So much for "not breaking other shortcuts involving Super".